# Ignorar nome da classe em serialização XML

Tags: c#, xml, serialização

Preciso serializar uma classe para XML, por exemplo:

```
public class Pessoa
{
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public int idade { get; set; }
    public Endereco endereco { get; set; }
}

public class Endereco
{
    public string logradouro { get; set; }
    public string numero { get; set; }
}
```

Serializando essa classe eu teria o seguinte XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Pessoa>
  <idade>66</idade>
  <Endereco>
     <logradouro>Rua 1</logradouro>
     <numero>123</numero>
  </endereco>
  <nome>João</nome>
</Pessoa>
```

O que eu precisaria é que as propriedades do endereço não ficassem dentro da tag `Endereco` e sim diretamente na tag `Pessoa`, dessa maneira:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Pessoa>
  <idade>66</idade>
  <logradouro>Rua 1</logradouro>
  <nome>João</nome>
  <numero>123</numero>
</Pessoa>
```

Não queria colocar as propriedades da classe `Endereco` diretamente na classe `Pessoa`, será que é possível de alguma maneira fazer isso?

Comment: Você está retornando sua classe de uma WebApi?

Comment: `ViewModel` seria a opção!

Comment: @joaoeduardorf, não entendi o motivo de sua pargunta. Tenho uma classe qualquer e vou serializá-la utiizando a classe [XmlSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) do `C#`, acredito que a maneira como eu obtenha os dados para ela não sejam relevantes. Pode esclarecer por gentileza?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, relamente ViewModel é uma opção, mas se for possível de outra maneira seria o ideal. =/

Comment: Claro @PedroCamaraJunior, vou colocar um exemplo como resposta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode controlar exatamente como será a serialização da sua classe para XML com a interface [`IXmlSerializable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx). Se você fizer a sua classe `Pessoa` implementar essa interface, você pode, no método `WriteXml`, escolher exatamente a forma que ela será emitida quando for serializada para XML. O código abaixo mostra um exemplo de implementação para o seu cenário.

```
public class PtStackOverflow_209719
{
    public class Pessoa : IXmlSerializable
    {
        public string nome { get; set; }
        public int idade { get; set; }
        public Endereco endereco { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Pessoa[nome={0},idade={1},endereco={2}]",
                this.nome, this.idade, this.endereco);
        }

        public XmlSchema GetSchema()
        {
            return null;
        }

        public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
        {
            reader.ReadStartElement("Pessoa");
            this.nome = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
            this.idade = reader.ReadElementContentAsInt();
            this.endereco = new Endereco();
            this.endereco.logradouro = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
            this.endereco.numero = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
            reader.ReadEndElement();
        }

        public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
        {
            writer.WriteElementString("nome", this.nome);
            writer.WriteElementString("idade", this.idade.ToString());
            writer.WriteElementString("logradouro", this.endereco.logradouro);
            writer.WriteElementString("numero", this.endereco.numero);
        }
    }
    public class Endereco
    {
        public string logradouro { get; set; }
        public string numero { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Endereco[logradouro={0},numero={1}]",
                this.logradouro, this.numero);
        }
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Pessoa));
        Pessoa p = new Pessoa
        {
            nome = "Fulano de Tal",
            idade = 33,
            endereco = new Endereco
            {
                logradouro = "Avenida Brasil",
                numero = "123"
            }
        };
        xs.Serialize(ms, p);
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray()));
        ms.Position = 0;
        Pessoa p2 = xs.Deserialize(ms) as Pessoa;
        Console.WriteLine(p);

        Console.WriteLine();

        ms = new MemoryStream();
        XmlSerializer xs2 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Pessoa[]));
        xs2.Serialize(ms, new Pessoa[] { p, p2 });
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray()));
        ms.Position = 0;
        Pessoa[] ap = xs2.Deserialize(ms) as Pessoa[];
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" - ", ap.Select(pp => pp.ToString())));
    }
}
```

Comment: Acho que esse é o caminho mesmo, implementar a interface e alterar o comportamento como eu preciso. Apenas precisei fazer algumas mudanças na sobre carga para que fique algo mais generico, pois as classes que estou usando são beem extensas. Se não se importar, posso editar sua resposta com minha solução final. Obrigado pela resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Diretamente com o XmlSerializer, você não conseguirá. Uma alternativa é tratar o XML com os métodos do XmlDocument após serializar com o XmlSerializer.

```
        //Instancia as classes
        Endereco e = new Endereco();
        e.logradouro = "Avenida Brasil";
        e.numero = "100";

        Pessoa p = new Pessoa();
        p.nome = "Julio";
        p.idade = 38;
        p.endereco = e;

        //Inicia XmlSerializer
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Pessoa));

        String XMLInicial;

        using (StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, p);
            XMLInicial = textWriter.ToString();
        }

        //Carrega String no XML
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.LoadXml(XMLInicial);

        //Obtem os ChildNodes de Endereco
        XmlNodeList NodesEndereco = xml.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Pessoa/endereco").ChildNodes;

        //Appenda Os nodes clonados para o XML dentro do NodeRoot
        for (int i = 0; i < NodesEndereco.Count; i++)
        {
            XmlNode nxn = NodesEndereco[i].Clone();
            xml.DocumentElement.AppendChild(nxn);
        }

        //Remove o node do Endereco e seus filhos
        XmlNode xn = xml.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Pessoa/endereco");
        xml.DocumentElement.RemoveChild(xn);

        //String com o resultado final
        String XMLFinal = xml.DocumentElement.OuterXml;
```

Comment: É uma solução também Julio, um pouco verbosa mas resolve o problema.  Porém acho que entre seu exemplo e utilizar uma ViewModel, ficaria com a ViewModel. De qualquer forma, ótima resposta. +1

Answer (score 1):

Se pode utilizar a ***classe*** [XmlDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.xml.xmldocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) da seguinte forma:

```
Pessoa p = new Pessoa();
p.nome = "Nome 1";
p.idade = 15;
p.endereco = new Endereco { logradouro = "Rua 1", numero = "15" };

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode docNode = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
doc.AppendChild(docNode);

XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("Pessoas");
doc.AppendChild(root);

XmlNode nome = doc.CreateNode("element", "Nome", null);
nome.InnerText = p.nome;
root.AppendChild(nome);

XmlNode idade = doc.CreateNode("element", "Idade", null);
idade.InnerText = p.idade.ToString();
root.AppendChild(idade);

XmlNode logradouro = doc.CreateNode("element", "Logradouro", null);
logradouro.InnerText = p.endereco.logradouro;
root.AppendChild(logradouro);

XmlNode numero = doc.CreateNode("element", "Numero", null);
numero.InnerText = p.endereco.numero;
root.AppendChild(numero);

doc.Save("./pessoa.xml");
```

---

***Saída:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Pessoas>
  <Nome>Nome 1</Nome>
  <Idade>15</Idade>
  <Logradouro>Rua 1</Logradouro>
  <Numero>15</Numero>
</Pessoas>
```

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [XmlDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.xml.xmldocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [XDocument Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx)
- [Writing XML with the XmlDocument class](http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/xml/writing-xml-with-the-xmldocument-class/)
- [XmlDocument.CreateElement Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw1ys7w6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Virgilio, dessa maneira irei criar um XML praticamente no "braço", já criei as classes para evitar esse tipo de trabalho. A classe que estou utilizando é bastante extensa, apenas citei um exemplo qualquer para ficar didático. Obrigado pela resposta mesmo assim. :)

Comment: @PedroCamaraJunior eu lhe dei a dica primordial que era criar um ViewModel nesse contexto, você ainda queria novidade e outras respostas, acredito que todas contribui para um determinado caso, inclusive o seu ... Foi minha maneira de ajudar ...! Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Pedro, este é o exemplo que falei:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace TesteComWebApi.Controllers
{
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public object Get(int id)
    {
        var pessoa = new Pessoa();
        var endereco = new Endereco();

        pessoa.nome = "Pedro Camara Junior";
        pessoa.idade = 30;
        endereco.logradouro = "Rua José da Silva";
        endereco.numero = "123";
        pessoa.endereco = endereco;

        return Ok(new{pessoa.nome, pessoa.idade, pessoa.endereco.logradouro, pessoa.endereco.numero});
    }

    // POST api/values
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // PUT api/values/5
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE api/values/5
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
}

public class Pessoa
{
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public int idade { get; set; }
    public Endereco endereco { get; set; }
}

public class Endereco
{
    public string logradouro { get; set; }
    public string numero { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: João, o que você está fazendo na prática é um WebService, que por padrão irá retornar um JSON da classe. O que eu preciso é a string XML mesmo, estou gerando um arquivo a partir dessa string. De qualquer forma, obrigado pela resposta.